# Define global NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

Is there a way to define a global NSMutableArray? I'd like to be able to declare the array so I can access/modify it across a series of instance methods. Here is the code that I have below and want to make sure this is how I should do it.

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> {
    NSMutableArray *sizedWordList;
}
```

In the .m:

```
sizedWordList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

- (void)dealloc
{
    [sizedWordList release];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you **do not** want a global variable but, instead, an instance variable. In that case, your declaration:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> {
    NSMutableArray *sizedWordList;
}
```

in the header file is correct. However, in the implementation file, you **cannot** do the following outside of an instance method (or, if it were indeed a global variable, outside of a class method or a function):

```
sizedWordList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

It is not legal in Objective-C. The correct place to initialise instance variables is the `-init` method. Since your class is a subclass of `UIViewController`, you should override its designated initialiser, `-initWithNibName:bundle:`:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nibBundle];
    if (self) {
        sizedWordList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Your `-dealloc` method is almost correct — remember that you should **always** send `[super dealloc]` at the end of your `-dealloc` method:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [sizedWordList release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Having done that, you can use the array in any other instance method. For instance,

```
- (void)logWordList {
    NSLog(@"%@", sizedWordList);
}
```

Comment: thanks. i actually declared the `sizedWordList` inside another instance method and not in the -init override. Is that ok?

Comment: @cfarm54 If you _declare_ a variable inside an instance method then it is a local/automatic variable and it only exists inside that method. On the other hand, you can instantiate your array in a method other than `-init…` but you need to bear in mind that that method must be called before the array becomes usable.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) and share the instance. A singleton will allow only one existing instance of a class to exist. So every accessing code uses the same instance.

Comment: I'd probably use a singleton as well in this situation, or set the NSMutableArray in the appDelegate if it's something that's appropriate in that class. Whenever I use a singleton I make use of the pattern shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like/145232#145232

Comment: A singleton is a class of which only 1 instance can exist ever. It's impossible to create multiple instances. Some people consider heavy use of singletons harmful, so one should be careful not to overuse it.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can create a class and import it where you want to use it.

header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

extern NSMutableArray * typesArray;

@interface GlobalVariables : NSObject {

}

@end
```

implementation

```
#import "GlobalVariables.h"

@implementation GlobalVariables

NSMutableArray * typesArray;

@end
```

Now you have acces to typesArray anywheare you import the header

Comment: super bro...u r a genius

Answer (score 0):

Create a singleton instance of the array in your AppDelegate and access it across your application.

```
**YourAppDelegate *delegate = (YourAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];**
```

'delegate.sizedWordList' is your global array

Try it out. Good luck.