# Why is my Objective-C class instance variable not being set?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

this is a noob question but I cannot for the life of me figure out why my MSMutableArray class variable is not being set. Below is my code:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
   NSMutableArray *imageArr;
}

@implementation MyClass
-(id)init
{
   self = [super init];
   if (self) {
      imageArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
   }
   return self;
}

- (void) checkImageArr {
   NSLog(@"imageArr size::%@",[imageArr count]);
}
```

When this code runs, the following is set to the log:

```
imageArr size::(null)
```

Why is that variable not being set? I looked at the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713816/define-global-nsmutablearray) and don't see anything different between my code and the accepted answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The %@ specifier expects the argument to be an `id` (or pointer to an object).  `-count` returns an NSUInteger which is not an object.  Since your array is empty, the count is zero and so the argument is being interpreted as a nil object, which comes out as `(null)` when used with the `%@` specifier.

If the argument was not nil, `-description` would be sent to it to get a string to insert in the log message.  So, if you add an object to your array, `NSLog` will try to interpret 1 as an object pointer and send `-description` to it.  This will cause an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception (try it!).

You need a format specifier that interprets the argument as a number.  `NSUinteger` has the following definition

```
#if __LP64__ || TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED || TARGET_OS_IPHONE || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
#else
typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
#endif
```

so it's probably an unsigned long.  For safety, I always cast it to make sure, so you need this:

```
NSLog(@"imageArr size::%lu", (unsigned long)[imageArr count]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change %@ to %lu and you'll see.

Answer (score 1):

The count method returns an NSUInteger.

Try this log format instead:

```
NSLog(@"imageArr size::%u",[imageArr count]);
```

Comment: It's a good idea to put a cast in because NSUInteger is not guaranteed to be an `unsigned int`

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"imageArr size::%@",[imageArr count]);
```

You should use %@ when you want to "write an object" AFAIK, it is like write [object description]. 
[imageArr count] is a int, right? It is not a pointer to an object.

You should use %i instead of %@. And size will be 0.

Try NSLog(@"imageArr size::%@",imageArr); if you want to write a address

Comment: `NSUInteger` is `unsigned long` on the iPhone so `%i` is wrong.